# Sql query to eliminate min and max

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets assume a table to be like

```
Acc_nbr  sal1 sal2 sal3 sal4
123          10    20     30   40
124           10   30      40   15
126           16    20      25    16
```

So in the above table i wanted to eliminate the min & max sal columns and only remaining sal columns need to be taken!

Eg: for acc_nbr 123 min sal =10 & max sal = 40
So as per my requirement i need to eliminate both 10 & 40, & need to take only 20&30.
Likewise the same to other acc_nbr's .
Please help.. thanks in advance!

Comment: What if you have ties?

Comment: Still eliminate them.. by considering one as min and another as max and remaining as they are. For eg: Sal1 sal2 sal3 sal4 40 40 40 40  In this case i want only two salaries that may be any.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hard problem for various reasons:

- Your data is not stored in a proper relational format.  However, even storing the data with one row per salary would not make this much easier.
- SQL in general does not have very good "intra-row" manipulation functionality.
- MySQL does not offer arrays or easy ways to unpivot the data.
- Duplicates and `NULL` values can be really troublesome.

If I assume that none of the values are `NULL` and you don't mind getting duplicates when there are ties at the extreme, then the following would work:

```
select t.*,
       (case when sal1 not in (least(sal1, sal2, sal3, sal4), greatest(sal1, sal2, sal3, sal4))
             then sal1
             when sal2 not in (least(sal1, sal2, sal3, sal4), greatest(sal1, sal2, sal3, sal4))
             then sal2
             when sal3 not in (least(sal1, sal2, sal3, sal4), greatest(sal1, sal2, sal3, sal4))
             then sal3
             when sal4 not in (least(sal1, sal2, sal3, sal4), greatest(sal1, sal2, sal3, sal4))
             then sal4
        end) as first_sal,
       (case when sal4 not in (least(sal1, sal2, sal3, sal4), greatest(sal1, sal2, sal3, sal4))
             then sal4
             when sal3 not in (least(sal1, sal2, sal3, sal4), greatest(sal1, sal2, sal3, sal4))
             then sal3
             when sal2 not in (least(sal1, sal2, sal3, sal4), greatest(sal1, sal2, sal3, sal4))
             then sal2
             when sal1 not in (least(sal1, sal2, sal3, sal4), greatest(sal1, sal2, sal3, sal4))
             then sal1
        end) as second_sal
from t;
```

I should note that this problem would be easier in almost any other database.

EDIT:

Golly, you don't mention how many columns you want in the output.  If we just `NULL` out the extrema, this is easier:

```
select t.*,
       (case when sal1 not in (least(sal1, sal2, sal3, sal4), greatest(sal1, sal2, sal3, sal4))
             then sal1
        end) as sal1,
       (case when sal2 not in (least(sal1, sal2, sal3, sal4), greatest(sal1, sal2, sal3, sal4))
             then sal1
        end) as sal2,
       (case when sal3 not in (least(sal1, sal2, sal3, sal4), greatest(sal1, sal2, sal3, sal4))
             then sal1
        end) as sal3,
       (case when sal4 not in (least(sal1, sal2, sal3, sal4), greatest(sal1, sal2, sal3, sal4))
             then sal1
        end) as sal4
from t;
```

This still assumes that the four `sal` values are not `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you! But can you please explain me what if there is a null value in sal1 and sal2 but remaining columns are not null ??

Answer (score 0):

Kind of merge sort

```
select Acc_nbr,  greatest(sal1,sal2) salA, least(sal3,sal4) salB
from (
    select Acc_nbr, sal1, least(sal2,sal3) sal2, greatest(sal2,sal3) sal3, sal4
    from (
        select Acc_nbr, least(sal1,sal2) sal1, greatest(sal1,sal2) sal2, least(sal3,sal4) sal3, greatest(sal3,sal4) sal4
        from tbl 
        ) t1
   ) t2;
```

Can be wrapped into single select, it just will be a bit more verbose.

Comment: What if there are no least and greatest functions support in certain database like sybase? How can we write this?

Comment: Looks like Sybase supports `APPLY` http://dcx.sybase.com/1101/en/dbusage_en11/apply-joins-joinsasp.html which makes in-row calculations rather simple task.

Comment: @user7600856 . . . This question is tagged MySQL.  The Sybase answer would be very different. Because this question has answers, I would suggest that you ask another question with the correct tag.  (Retagging this answer will invalidate the answers and that draws downvotes.)